# Wordpress sidebar content moving to bottom of page

Tags: css, sidebar

Ever since my previous website update (developer no longer with me), I am having an issue with Wordpress widgets on my sidebar moving to *below* the content, rather than remaining on the sidebar on https://morpheustrading.com/blog/.

The issue seems to be that **ALL widgets are moving to the bottom of the page if the text content is too wide in any individual widget.**

For example, a narrow HTML block of code remains on the sidebar, but all widgets move to the bottom if I try to use a widget such as "Most Popular Posts" or "Related Posts" because the text in these widgets is apparently too long.

**Rather than wrapping the text, the whole widget moves to the bottom.**

I have spent hours Googling and trying different solutions to adjust the width of the sidebar, but still have not managed to resolve the issue.

Maybe I only need to set the text to wrap, rather than adjust the sidebar width. Not sure, as my coding experience is limited.

My Wordpress site is using a **custom theme built on underscores.me.**

Would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: do you mean the blog posts, you want them at the side? from the link you provided, I can't see what the issue is.

Comment: this looks like a CSS/styling issue, you shouldn't need WordPress expertise or knowledge to solve this

Comment: @mir The current sidebar is displaying properly because I am using narrow enough text content. However, If I try to use a basic widget such as Related Posts or Most Popular Posts, then ALL widgets move to the bottom of the page because the title text of the links is wider than the sidebar widget AND the text is not wrapping.

Sorry if I was not clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this css property:

`word-wrap: break-word;`

There is a few others:

```
overflow-wrap: normal;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: anywhere;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Does this code go in Appearance --> Additional CSS section? Or style.css? Sorry that my experience level is minimal, but I am trying hard.  :-)

Comment: it can go into either section but you need to target the correct class, so if it is within the .sidebar section you would write .sidebar{ word-wrap: break-word;} You should always test css changes with the developer tools of your browser before applying them. also for a live website, you may need to purge the cache after applying the changes. this may affect performance temporarily of the website. if you can set your website to the appearance that is wrong I can have a look and try see if I can recommend anything

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help, but still having same issue after trying to add .sidebar{ word-wrap: break-word;}  in Additional CSS and then again trying in sidebar.php.

I tested by adding Most Popular Posts widget, but it still causes all widgets to go to bottom of page due to the width.

Comment: it may not be sidebar class that you are targeting. I can't see the class in your website. if you publish those widgets that set them to the wrong position temporarily, i can take a look, and see if i can help further

Comment: your sidebar is an id of #sidebar-1 so it would be #sidebar-1{ word-wrap: break-word;}

Comment: @dieseldog have you a staging website to test your changes

Comment: First, I sincerely appreciate you taking the time to try to help further. I have added one of the widgets that was causing the sidebar content to go to the bottom of the page (Most Recent Posts). If you look now, you will see all sidebar content moved to the bottom when I added that. 

I do not have a staging website currently, but I back up the original code before making changes to any files.

Comment: I see what the problem is. your website is using bootstrap and the sidebar has no class added, so it went back to the side when i added class="col-sm-4" to your sidebar div <div id="sidebar-1" class="col-sm-4"> however, I am not sure how you would implement this without editing template files, unless your blog page has a custom template that your developer created. to explain further your primary section ( the blog posts ) has a col-sm-8, and it can only be 12 columns so that is why i used 4 for the sidebar so that they would appear alongside each other. <div id="primary" class="col-sm-8">

Comment: IT WORKED! I am so happy because I have been trying to fix this for a LONG time on my own and it was a simple fix after you explained it. I am most truly appreciative and hope to pay your effort forward. Thank you again.

Comment: hi im so glad it helped. there is potentially other ways around it, but that is what i would do, it seems the most logical.